# Read-out-loud and mathematics

Tags: packages, compiling, viewers, teaching

If a reader has a vision disability, ADHD, dyslexia or some other learning disabilities, it is common to use read-out-loud tools (such as EasyReader, TorTalk, Claro read, Natural readers, and also Acrobat reader). However, I have not found such tools which work for mathematics.

Is there something one can use in latex for this?

Perhaps a package that creates a companion text- or mp3-file when the code is parsed during compilation.

---

Also, suggestions of read-out-loud tools working for mathematics are welcome (sorry if that is off-topic).

---

Comment: we are working on improving tagging in pdf, but currently you may want to try converting to html with math as mathjax (eg using make4ht), mathjax has quite reasonable voice support for mathematics

Comment: https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/basic/accessibility.html

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I should look into mathjax. 

Yes, I have understood that tagging of PDF's are difficult in TeX-code.  At my university we use Canvas and whenever you upload a pdf it complains about the tagging, and later I understood there was a connection to accessibility.  
I thought there might be other ways to solve this issue, perhaps without PDF's?

Comment: @AD. That's really a question about the capabilities of the Canvas VLE, which would be off-topic here.

Comment: I think we might be at the same university and department. Even with a correctly tagged pdf file, the sound file you will get out from canvas is just wrong. I don't know what you need this for, but my guess is that you should look for non-pdf solutions at the moment. Perhaps some more structured format has better support.

Comment: @mickep Maybe the same university :) 
I am at Lund university, my last place was at the department of health sciences (a month ago), but I have worked at the mathematics center too.